# EGit Conflicts with every pull

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am new to Git which is different from all the other source control tools I have administered.

In my situation, I have an android project which is on the remote repository and my Friend and I both added this to our eclipse. The project is a couple of days old, where My friend made a couple of changes to a few files and committed and pushed it to the repository.

I on the other hand, didn't make any changes but got conflicts on all the files he changed when I did a egit pull. I did a hard reset and clean to get things back to normal since I didnt make any changes. Then the next day he pushed a few more changes and the same thing happened, conflicts on files he changed.

Is this normal for git? I am kinda scared to proceed with Git knowing that these conflict happen without any changes on the other end. What should I do to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you guys using different development environments? Mac/Linux/Windows? Are the conflicts due to line-endings?

Comment: I use Windows7 and he uses a Mac. Is that an issue? I dont think the conflicts are due to line endings. When I diff it, its the same, but yet is says it conflicted.. The Merge Tool is greyed out also, so I cant tell git to choose the remote version etc..

Comment: It's line-endings. In Git settings, add `autocrlf = false` and `whitespace cr-at-eol` under core.

Comment: Thanks. Going to try this. I noticed that "whitespace" didnt exist on mines, so I added that entry. This should be fine, right?

Comment: Hey - can you add this to the answer section. We added these git settings and so far so good. Amazing. Thanks.

Comment: So glad I could help. I used to do a lot of mixed development as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're working in both Mac (Linux) and Windows environments, you'll wind up dealing with issues due to different line-endings. You can instruct EGit to not modify line-endings on pull and ignore differences, by adding/modifying core settings. In preferences, navigate to Git settings and add:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    whitespace = cr-at-eol
```